# No compatible GPUs found for the path tracking

Tags: opencl

The error when open Blender as I am using the AWS instance G4x4large (GPU Tesla T4). As I read here this GPU support OpenCL [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/grid/latest/grid-vgpu-user-guide/#cuda-open-cl-support)
[image: The driver version]
[image]

Comment: Make sure you're using the most up to date drivers.

Comment: Not an expert here, but shouldn't this Nvidia card support Cuda or even OptiX?

Comment: OpenCL is only used for AMD GPUs, check in the CUDA or OptiX tab.